# React-scroll stopped working after turning a nodejs project into a yarn project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarn-v2, react-scroll

I have a project that I originally built with node.js, however I switched it over to yarn. Everything works, except for the react-scroll. I have uninstalled and reinstalled it and verified that it is still in package.json. Anyone else ran into this issue before or have any troubleshooting tips?
Here is a cut of my code for a button I want to link to a section of the site:

```
import { Link } from 'react-scroll';

<Link
activeClass='active'
to="portfolio"
smooth
duration={500}
className='group flex items-center rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-indigo-600 w-fit text-white font-bold px-5 py-3 space-x-2'
>
 <div>Portfolio</div>
 <span className='group-hover:rotate-90 duration-300'>
  <MdOutlineArrowRightAlt />
 </span>
</Link>
```

And here is the code for the piece I want to link to:

````
<div id="portfolio">
 <div>
  <p>stuff in here and words </p>
 </div>
</div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. I had overflow settings in my App.js file. This caused an error and wouldn't allow scroll to work. If anyone else ever gets stuck with this, just see if you have overflow in any classNames. :)